# in bootstrap there is <hr>, is there something like that but for vertical divider?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to accomplish something like this

[image]

I am aware that with bootstrap you can use the `<hr>` to make a horizontal division, I need to make a vertical divider, is there something like that or I have to use CSS ?

Comment: wouldn't it be nice if such a thing as a `<vr>` existed... No you'll need to use CSS. Looking at the pic, I'd suggest a left border on the navigation links...

Comment: can you help me with the css @Ted http://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/PwRBQy

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer `<hr>` has nothing to do with bootstrap. It's an [HTML element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/hr), and has existed since the pre-bootstrap days.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer check my answer, I attached jsfiddle link.

Comment: Sure, see this [forked codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwRBey)--all that's needed is this:`.navbar-nav>li>a{border-left:1px solid #ffffff}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case "More" and "My Account" are `DIV`s or other `block-type` elements.
Give them the same css class and apply the following style:

```
.sideborders {
    border-width: 1px 2px 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ozoov8f9/ example, adjust the `div` contents to your likings.

Play with it, alternatively `border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;`